# ¿Cómo relacionar o unir 3 tablas para realizar una consulta en MySQL?

Tags: php, html5, mysqli

Anteriormente estuve buscando un ejemplo con `JOIN` para unir 2 tablas y lo conseguí y me funciona muy bien. Pero eso fue con 2 tablas nada más.

Mi proyecto es de hacer posts, que los usuarios puedan hacerlo. La parte que me funciona es esta:

```
$query_buscar_posts = mysqli_query($conn, " SELECT posts.Id, 
      posts.Titulo, 
      posts.Contenido, 
      personas.Fotos,
      personas.nombre,
      personas.apellido
  FROM posts
  LEFT JOIN personas
  ON posts.User_Id = personas.Id 
  WHERE posts.User_Id = $my_id") or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
```

Esto me imprime cada post del usuario logueado, lo cual lo hago o mejor dicho lo imprimo con un **"echo"**, pero ahora estoy por implementarle un sistema de comentarios para cada post.

La caja de texto de hacer comentario ya funciona,pero solo enviando los comentarios a la base de datos, según el Id del usuario que lo hace.

El problema radica en hacer la consulta para traer los comentarios de cada post.

Las tablas son:

**personas**,

```
Id
Nombre
Apellido
Correo
Password
Fotos
```

**posts**,

```
Id
User_Id
Contenido
```

**comentarios**

```
id
contenido
fecha
id_usuario
id_post
```

Como dije anteriormente ya puedo hacer publicaciones solo que me gustaría incluir los comentarios en ese `JOIN`. Pienso que es mejor en la misma consulta.

Comment: ¿Con qué campo Id de la tabla `comentarios` deseas hacer el `JOIN`? ¿Sería con el `id_usuario`?

Answer (score 2):

Ya capté lo que requieres hacer. A tu query le faltaría solamente hacer el `JOIN` con la taba `comentarios`:

**UPDATE**

También es necesario poner `AND posts.User_Id = comentarios.id_usuario` para que se respete la relación de todos los comentarios de un solo usuario.

```
$query_buscar_posts = mysqli_query($conn, "
  SELECT posts.Id, 
      posts.Titulo, 
      posts.Contenido, 
      personas.Fotos,
      personas.nombre,
      personas.apellido,
      comentarios.contenido,
      comentarios.fecha
  FROM posts
  INNER JOIN comentarios
     ON comentarios.id_post = post.Id AND posts.User_Id = comentarios.id_usuario
  INNER JOIN personas
     ON posts.User_Id = personas.Id 
  WHERE posts.User_Id = $my_id") or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
```

Comment: Amigo he  logrado hacerlo.Pregunta.......El orden de los JOINs afecta en algo?Ademas de eso cuando escribo el primer comentario funciona bien,pero cuando escribo el segundo,pasa que me publica otro post.

Comment: No, el orden no afecta. Ya sé cual es el problema, voy a ver si puedo editar la respuesta, hace falta completar un `JOIN`

Comment: Listo, revisa si con esa actualización a la respuesta te funciona como esperas

Answer (score 1):

Me tome el tiempo de hacer una BD en sucio de lo que propones:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero en realidad ayude

Comment: Solamente tengo que tomar el codigo sql y adaptarlo verdad?

Comment: pues la verdad si, como te digo, está en sucio y como puedes notar puedes hacer otro join luego de estos por si quieres agregar otra tabla.

Comment: Viendo la lógica y contenido de cada tabla la relación que propones no sería la correcta, debido a que según la estructura de campos la tabla `personas` se relaciona con `posts` y a su vez `post` con `comentarios`

Comment: @Vicete Geovanny Franco Siles Te contare después para ver si me funciono.

Comment: Considera la información que requieres, tal vez todos no todos tus posts tengan comentarios, o tal vez tus comentarios no están en todos tus posts, con un INNER join harás exclusiones de tus posts

Comment: @EdGarcía, Puede hacer excepciones si es que regresa comentario como vacío, pero eso sería después. Yo primero me enfocaría en el mayor resultado que espero en la consulta y luego verificar si existe regreso o no de la consulta. O cosas asi.

Comment: @ViceteGeovannyFrancoSiles entiendo tu punto, pero a lo que iba es que es probable que existan post's que no tengan comentarios, por lo que la tabla principal debería ser esa, de personas no estoy seguro si es usuarios finales o creadores de posts, si es del 2do debería ser left join y si es del primero inner join.
Con el query como lo sugieres puede haber exclusiones de posts.

Comment: @EdGarcía Tienes razón, en el ejemplo que plantee solo me enfoque en unir las tablas. Ya depende de el que tipo de JOIN usar.